# How to access a method from fragment class to adapter class

Tags: java, android, fragment, adapter

I want to use `reloadTransList()` method in the onClick function in the adapter class. This is the method in a fragment class.

`translistTab.java`

```
public void reloadTransList() {
    productTransList.clear();
    transRecyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
    loadTransList();
}
```

And this is how I called it in the adapter class.

`prodAdapter.java`

```
translistTab translistTab = new translistTab();
translistTab.reloadTransList();
```

**EDIT:**

The method now is being called. But the `loadproducts();` is not working without errors. The `loadproducts()` method is the loading of products in recyclerview. The method is running, but the recyclerview is not reloading.

Comment: You can pass a link of your fragment to ur adapter class as part of initialisation e.g adapter = new Adapter(Fragment.this, xx)

Comment: This adapter is for the other fragment. Not this fragment

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you forgot to add setOnCLickListner(this) in your ViewHolder inner class in the adapter. If you add this, you would be able to call reloadTransList() from onClick() method.

Comment: I have added this sir. Also I have a nullpointerexeption for this

Answer (score 0):

A short answer is to pass the fragment into your adapter via constructor or setter.

A longer, better answer is to define a custom interface that gets implemented by your fragment and passed into your adapter. The implemented interface will contain your `reloadTransList()` method

**EDIT**

I don't know exactly how your classes are setup, but the long solution would look something like the following.

First, define a interface.

```
public interface MyCustomInterface {
    void onCustomAction();
}
```

The exact implementation can vary depending on your needs.

Next, in your fragment class, implement the interface. Place the `reloadTransList()` method inside.

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements MyCustomInterface {
    // All your other, unrelated Fragment code

    @Override
    public void onCustomAction() {
        reloadTransList();
    }
}
```

Now, in your adapter class. Pass the Interface (not the Fragment) into the adapter and assign it to an instance variable. I personally prefer to do that via constructor:

```
public class prodAdapter extends Adapter { // I'm only assuming the adapter you are using. It has no relevance to this

    private MyCustomInterface customInterface;

    public prodAdapter(MyCustomInterface customInterface) {
        this.customInterface = customInterface;
    }
}
```

From there, simply call `customInterface.onCustomAction()` wherever you need the `reloadTransList()` method fired.

The short solution is just like the above code, except with just the fragment and no interface. Strongly recommend you go the long way. Especially for testing purposes.

**EDIT #2**

Another advantage to the long solution is you can re-use the adapter in another class without changing it. For your other fragments using the adapter, implement the `MyCustomInterface`.

```
public class AnotherFragment extends Fragment implements MyCustomInterface {
    @Override
    public void onCustomAction() {
        // Put whatever you need here. Or nothing.
    }
}
```

This allows the adapter to be re-used across multiple fragments.

Comment: Can you elaborate more what is an custom interface is? I'm new in android development

Comment: I have looked for this in the other questions here. But I really don't understand

Comment: Where will I define interface?

Comment: @MikaelFaire Anywhere. It's public.

Comment: Can I ask if I do this, do the recyclerview will reload or not?

Comment: @MikaelFaire Based on your code, I would assume so. I didn't change the function of your code. I just provided a means for you to access it from your adapter.

Comment: Okay, I'm trying this

Comment: I think there is one thing that you've not posted

Comment: What will I put in the other fragment if the adapter is called or the constructor of the adapter is called

Comment: Or where else can I pass the interface other than the constructor?

Comment: @MikaelFaire You can pass it in via a setter method. Other fragment? Is the adapter located in another fragment?

Comment: It is located in the other fragment

Comment: @MikaelFaire So this adapter is used in several fragments?

Comment: Yes. In items display, and in search

Comment: The argument, customInterface. What will I pass into the customInterface when I will declare this adapter to a fragment. ex `adapter = new ProductAdapter(mCtx, productList, customInterface);recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);` How can I pass the argument to the adapter

Comment: @MikaelFaire `this`